# How do I get the Primary Key of a table in a Hyper Database?

Tags: python, sql

With Python, I'd like to extract the column or columns of a table in a Hyper Database which are specified as the primary key, if the table has a primary key at all.

This is the query I've tried, which is just what ChatGPT has suggested to do. Unfortunately, I get the HyperException that the schema 'information_schema' does not exist. 'input_hyper_path' is the path to the main data file of the Hyper database.

```
import pathlib
import tableauhyperapi

with HyperProcess(telemetry=Telemetry.DO_NOT_SEND_USAGE_DATA_TO_TABLEAU) as hyper:
    with Connection(endpoint=hyper.endpoint, database=input_hyper_path) as connection:
        for schema in connection.catalog.get_schema_names():
            if str(schema.name) == '"Extract"':
                table_names = connection.catalog.get_table_names(schema=schema)
                for table in table_names:
                    with connection.execute_query(f"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{table}' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY_KEY'") as result:
                        rows = list(result)
                        for row in rows:
                            print(row)
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] the full error message, starting from the word "Traceback", into your post, properly formatted in a code block?

Comment: ChatGPT is rarely a source of good, working code and definitely not for specific libraries. I would highly recommend you to try yourself to create a solution. We aren't here to resolve your minimal-effort, buggy code, but if you have a specific question about self-written code, we are glad to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @The_spider, I have been trying different things for several hours, including reading the manual of the api. This is just what seemed to be the most promising starting point, which is why I added it to my post. So if you have any helpful comment or even a solution, I am glad to read it. :)

Comment: It would be useful if you added your own attempts, so that we can correct them and you can learn what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On top of learning to program, learning to use Stackoverflow and learning to use ChatGPT turn out to be an art on themselves, let alone the combination ; )

Your problem might be caused by your method being made for other types of databases than Tableau. I used to think that the S in SQL stood for 'standardized', but it does not.

This would be more adapted to Tableaus Hyper database:

```
import pathlib
import tableauhyperapi

with tableauhyperapi.HyperProcess(telemetry=tableauhyperapi.Telemetry.DO_NOT_SEND_USAGE_DATA_TO_TABLEAU) as hyper:
    with tableauhyperapi.Connection(endpoint=hyper.endpoint, database=input_hyper_path) as connection:
        # Assuming you are interested in the 'Extract' schema
        schema = 'Extract'
        table_names = connection.catalog.get_table_names(schema=schema)
        for table_name in table_names:
            # Get the definition of the table
            table_definition = connection.catalog.get_table_definition(name=table_name)
            if table_definition is not None:
                # Check for primary key columns
                primary_keys = [col.name for col in table_definition.columns if col.is_primary_key]
                print(f"Primary Key columns in table {table_name}: {primary_keys}")
```

Comment: Okay, the column object has no attribute is_primary_key, so your approach does not work either. Also I do not know how to interpret the first sentence of your answer. If it is plain sarcasm which makes fun of my coding skills, I believe it to be completely out of place and very, very arrogant. Not only because your approach does not work either, but considering that even more so.

Comment: No it was not meant sarcastically at all, quite the opposite. I was trying to counteract the tone that had arisen before. It really was written in attempt to cheer you up, apologies that this did not come across. It is hard to test database related code, especially other peoples databases. is_primary_key is not an attribute, it gets the primary key. Every table has a primary key. When you share the error message it is easier to deduct where the issue comes from

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying, I really appreciate that! Sorry for misunderstanding that one.

Comment: This is the error msg:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../primary_key.py", line 20, in <module>
    primary_keys = [col.name for col in table_definition.columns if col.is_primary_key]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/.../primary_key.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    primary_keys = [col.name for col in table_definition.columns if col.is_primary_key]
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Column' object has no attribute 'is_primary_key'